# Flex 3.5 binding fails if destination starts with 'result'

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

Well, as weird as the title may seem, the following application fails to work as expected in Flex3.5:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical">
    <mx:TextInput id='ti'/>
    <mx:Text id='result' text="{ti.text}"/>
</mx:Application>
```

In response to the comment and to add more clarity to the question: here, the Binding mechanism doesn't update the `result` Text on typing in `ti`.

Comment: What exactly is failing ?

Comment: Binding doesn't work. The text never gets updated. I already know the answer, but I wanted to post the question, so that some other poor soul gets saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a day of debugging and scrutinizing generated actionscript, the issue was found to be the name of the `Text` element. Renaming it to anything else works. I know why it failed after looking at the generated code -- generated code has an internal variable 'result' which clashes with the destination name here. So, this works. Notice `result1`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical">
    <mx:TextInput id='ti'/>
    <mx:Text id='result1' text="{ti.text}"/>
</mx:Application>
```

The reason of my post is that I wish someone else who gets this messed up behavior would find something useful in google!

I also have a question here. I tried the same thing with Flex 4 and it didn't fall into the same fallacy. Flex 4 also generated code with and internal variable name 'result', but fortunately the clash was avoided as the destFunction in Binding constructor was set to null. OTOH, in Flex3.5, it's passed an anonymous function which does the actual assignment `result.text=value`, thereby resulting in a confusion for the compiler.
My question being, can I convince Flex4 to generate similar anonymous function (and hence have the same bug)?